# Autoformat in tabbing environment

Tags: tabbing

is there a way to make the first row in a tabbing environment bold?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{libertinus} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[greek,ngerman]{babel} 
  
\begin{document} 
   \begin{tabbing} 
    τερπικέραυνος:~~ \= (1) Ende, Ziel, Grenze, Limit, (2)  Kulmination, höchster Punkt, Ziel, Preis, (3) höchste Macht, Suprema\kill 
    τεράτευμα: \> Jongliertrick\\ 
    τερατογόνος: \> die Geburt eines Ungeheuers/eine Missgeburt begünstigen\\ 
    τερέω: \> durchbohren, stechen\\ 
    \end{tabbing} 
\end{document}
```

In this case I want all the greek words bold, but I don't want to use \bfseries again and again.
Is there a way to automat this?

~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `tabularry`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{libertinus} 
\usepackage[greek,ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{column{1}={font=\bfseries,l}, column{2}={l}}
    τερπικέραυνος:~~ & {(1) Ende, Ziel, Grenze, Limit,                         \\
                        (2) Kulmination, höchster Punkt, Ziel, Preis,          \\
                        (3) höchste Macht, Suprema}                            \\
    τεράτευμα:       & Jongliertrick                                           \\
    τερατογόνος:     & die Geburt eines Ungeheuers/eine Missgeburt begünstigen \\
    τερέω:           & durchbohren, stechen                                    \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]